# Неудачно инициализирующиеся случайные веса простой нейросети

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Есть некоторая функция распознавания изображений, использующая в этих целях нейросеть. Для ясности: она принимает объект А, объект Б и неопределенный объект. Ее задача определить: третий А или Б? Тренировочные данные - известные объекты. Пока что опустим этот момент.

Подробней о процессе тренировки этой нейросети. Существуют такие случайне инициализации весов, при которых нейросеть не тренируется. То есть **ошибка распознавания** на втором слое остается **в пределах 0.5 +- 0.05 или 0.25 +- 0.05.**

Эти случаи я определяю в самом процессе тренировки: если на больших повторах ошибка больше порога, то
повторяем весь процесс обучения с момента инициализации весов. То есть **пытаемся с новыми весами.**

Все бы ничего, но термиты проедают деревянный костыль этого простуженного кода. Онная **функция вызывается тучу раз.** Процесс тренировки занимает, скажем, приемлемые 2 секунды. Это с учетом 1 повтра обучения. А этих самых повторов может быть разно как! Хоть 2, 10, 18, 25. Что хочешь... Терпимо. Не это причина моего вопроса. Я столкнулся с следующим: **безрезультатные 400+ повторов. Каждый раз весы неудачно инициализировались. Нейросеть не могла преодолеть этот рубикон порога ошибки. Во всех повторах ошибка колебалась в обозначеных ранее пределах.**

О случайной инициализации и самой нейросети. Нейросеть взята из этой [статьи](https://habr.com/ru/post/271563/). Как и нейросеть, сама функция сильно адаптирована под конкретную задачу. Привести полный код будет достаточно затруднительно. Поэтому оставляю статью. **Можете смело листать в конец. Код моей неросети практически не отличается.**

Сама инициализация весов:

```
in_connections =numpy.prod(объект_а.shape)
out_connections=2#  так как у нас два изображения в тренировочных данных. На самом деле у меня их больше.
syn0=2 * numpy.random.random((in_connections, out_connections)) - 1
syn1=2 * numpy.random.random((out_connections, 1)) - 1
```

1. Уже пытался решить (жалкая попытка) изменением numpy.random.seed(на_случайное_число) по времени работы программы (не превышало 100, не повторялось, менялось каждые 10 неудачных обучений).
2. Уже пытался повторить 400+ безрезультатиков на отдельно вынесеном тесте. То есть я взял плохих парней (сами данные, при которых происходит онная проблема) и в отдельном тестике не смог повторить проблему с 51 попытки. Рекорд менее 90. Тест был в два тира: с и без первого пункта.

*Возможно это лишнее, но у плохих парней 4 изображения с выходом 1 и 3 изображения с выходом 0.*

Воот.. Этот костыль можно сделать железным? Может можно оценить насколько хорошо инициализированы веса и тем самым убрать 1000+ циклов заведомо плохого обучения? Или все же есть лекарство? Даже догадок о нем нету, но не будет код ни болеть, ни быть инвалидомx).

Comment: У вас проблема в чём состоит - выхотите обязательно написать свою нейросеть? Тогда вам придётся учить теорию. Дело может быть много в чём. У вас может нехватать нейронов или слоёв для хорошего обучения. Вам нужно будет бороться в процессе очень много с какими вещами, если вы будете писать нейросеть сами. Гораздо проще взять какой-нибудь Keras и попробовать разные конфигурации сети. Бывает, что dropout слой помогает, бывает, что функция активации должна быть другая. А может в вашем случае без CNN слоя никуда. Проще использовать готовую библиотеку, чем бороться сразу со всем вручную.

Comment: @CrazyElf, проблема инициализации весов именно на больших повторах вызова функции. Нейросеть безрезультатно пытается тренироваться 400+ раз за неприемлемый интервал времени. Притом графики ее трернировки имеют общий характер. Вот он: [график](https://prnt.sc/rrzkef) ((имеется ввиду вероятность ошибки)), [период](https://prnt.sc/rrzkk8). Процесс обучения приемлем, если вероятность уже меньше 20 при 10 (условых едениц) обучения. Тут же непонятные периоды полного простоя и однообразные скачки туда - обратно. Возможно dropout поможет, еще не проверил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите,сделал такую сеть (2,3,1),тренировалась на логическом ИЛИ,есть кросс валидация,инициализация весов по Хе,активация Relu и вот при данных параметрах - 100% кросс валидация:
топология: именно (2,3,1)
learning rate - 0.07
np.random.seed(42) - если изменишь на 40 - уже 25%

Я думаю надо делать адаптивный learning_rate .
Я визуализировал с помощью Pillow в своей топологии сети для слоя с входами==2,где
seed(42)
[image: seed(42)]

И с seed(40):
[image: seed(40)]

Видно в первой они более равномерно распределены(по Гауссу(по Хе))

Answer (score 0):

Я доработал программу,теперь выдает значение положительных чисел как серых.Картинки вторая с зерном 42 показывает(кроме того,что описал выше),что положительные числа близки к нулю(еле серы),первая при зерне 30 все не так(далековаты от 0).
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLu2F.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLu2F.png)
[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox1MA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox1MA.png)